# Issues Connecting to DNS on Windows Server 2016 from RSAT on Windows 10 Pro

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, virtual-machines, windows-server-2016

I will make this as concise as I can.
Background: I am trying to set up a collection of Windows 2016 VMs to test through some labs but I am having issues connecting as my title states.

This is the error I received when trying to connect from my Windows 10 Pro VM to my Windows Server 2016 Core DNS server (DC1).

[Attempted Connection From Windows 10 to DC1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhhaR.png)

All firewalls are open on both sides.
Running from Admin on both VMs.
Tried to uncomment the hostfile as said on some forums.
VMs have all of the updates available.
Went back through config to make sure it was all correct.
Checked network setting, etc.
Did a good bit of googling for the past few days and nothing they suggest seems to work so far.

Here are my configurations on DC1 (Windows Server 2016 Core) my VirtualBox network, and Windows 10 Pro /w RSAT.

Windows Server 2016 (DC1):
[DC1 Netowkr Interface Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhhaR.png)

I have ran the following commands:

New-NetFirewallRule -Display "Allow All Traffic" -Direction Inbound -Action Allow

New-NetFirewallRule -Display "Allow All Traffic" -Direction Outbound -Action Allow

Get-WindowsFeature

Get-WindowsFeature dns

[DC1 DNS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSoHq.png)

I have done all the updates through sconfig that are available.

Windows 10 Pro /w RSAT:
Network Adaptor setting are the same as DC1 other than IP address of 192.168.3.99.

All updates have been done, network to c$ have been established, firewall rules the same as DC1 and I have disable all firewalls.

[Network c$ from Windows 10 to DC1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYb2x.png)

VM Network:
Set up as a NAT Network 192.168.3.0/24
With my host machines VM adapter being:

[Host Adapter Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGE0m.png)

I do not have much experience connecting VMs together. I am just going from my knowledge of networking.
I do not have much experience setting up Windows 2016 but I am building this stuff so I can learn but I have been having this issue for 2-3 days.

Comment: I think your first image link is to the wrong image.

Comment: Thank, you. I fixed it.